# Using org.python.core.PyList in Jython via Matillion AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jython, matillion

I am running a Python Script Component in Matillion ETL for Redshift. That component is using Jython, with the below code. I am getting an error on the context.updateGridVariable line because of an object conversion error.

I would like to know how I can instantiate a org.python.core.PyList object, so that I can populate it, instead of the java.lang.String that I am getting.

**Output**

[u's3://bucket-landingzone/inbox/dt_employees_20180614.csv']
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ClassCastException: **java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.python.core.PyList** in  at line number 26

**Code**

```
import boto3
import json

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = "bucket-landingzone"
name = "inbox/dt_employee_20180615"
file_list = []

manifest_object = s3.Object(bucket,name)

file_content = manifest_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
json_content = json.loads(file_content)

for entry in json_content['entries']:
  for attribute, value in entry.iteritems():
    if attribute == 'url':
        file_list.append(value)

print(file_list)

context.updateGridVariable('manifest_entries', file_list)

print(context.getGridVariable('manifest_entries'))
```

Comment: To wrap your string, `'manifest_entries'`, in a list, simply surround it with square brackets.

Comment: I believe that the error is referring to the file_list as not a list. This is the syntax for the updateGridVariable method: context.updateGridVariable('mygridvar', [['list','of'],['lists','!']]). 'manifest_entries' is the name of the grid variable, while the file_list is the contents.

Comment: @DavidCharles your comment led me in the correct direction. If you want to post an answer that the brackets in this line of code will fix it, I will mark it as the answer.... file_list.append([value])